# How can I combine this value and add into tableview row?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, google-distancematrix-api

I have a list value from google distant matrix api along with the list of destination. What i’ve done now is:

1) Get the output destination list google places api and current location (lon & lat) from geolocation.
2) List of destination and current location (lon & lat) has output the list of distant and duration from google distant matrix api.

Now there are two separate output, which is a list value from google distant matrix and destination list.

Both were taken to the output function for display to the tableview. So the problem now is, how I wanted to combine these two values and display in tableview row?

I need to combine this value and add into tableview row. What i have now is only last value added into tableview row. Lets see the code and image:

```
var getValue = function(matrix,all) {
    var matrix;
    var all;
    //Ti.API.info(matrix);
    //Ti.API.info(all);
    var section = Titanium.UI.createTableViewSection();
    var data = [];

    for (var i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)    
    {       
         var distance = matrix[i].elements[0].distance.text;
         Ti.API.info(distance);     

         var lblDist = Ti.UI.createLabel({
         width: 'auto', height: 23, left: 52,
         textAlign: "left", font: {fontSize: 10, fontFamily:"HelveticaNeue-Bold"}, bottom: -2});
         lblDist.text = distance;       
    };    

    for (var c=0;c<all.length;c++)    
    {

         var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:45,selectedBackgroundColor: '#dbd9cc'}); 

         var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({left:52,top:2,        
         width:245,height:30,font:{fontFamily:'Open Sans',fontSize:20,fontWeight:'bold'}});

         var sTitle = all[c].name;
         label.text = sTitle;
         //lblDist.text = distance;

         row.add(label);
         row.add(lblDist);
         section.add(row);
         tableview.data=[section]; 
         self.add(tableview);   
    }
};
```

When I did `Ti.API.info(distance);` it will list all output that I want to add into tableview. Right now only the last value add into tableview.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but you have several problems in your code snippet.

Let me try to help you with some points.

1. You need to pay attention to declaration, scope and hoisting of variables in JavaScript [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)]. And then, you will realize that in the end of your first loop you will only store the last *Label* object, in your case, the *Label* with text = 1.0km
2. In your second loop, the same error happens. You are adding to the screen *all.length* times the *tableview* on the screen.
3. You need to understand that those two loops will runs one after other, sequentially. Then, this solution will only works if both loops have the same length.

Based on the third point, I can write a example solution.

```
var getValue = function(matrix,all) {
     var lblDist = null;
     var label = null;
     var data = [];

     for (var i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
          var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:45,selectedBackgroundColor: '#dbd9cc'}); 
          lblDist = Ti.UI.createLabel({width:'auto', height: 23, left: 52, textAlign: "left", font: {fontSize: 10, fontFamily:"HelveticaNeue-Bold"}, bottom: -2});
          lblDist.text =  matrix[i].elements[0].distance.text;       
          label = Ti.UI.createLabel({left:52,top:2,width:245,height:30,font:{fontFamily:'Open Sans',fontSize:20,fontWeight:'bold'}});
          label.text = matrix[i].elements[0].name.text;
          row.add(label);
          row.add(lblDist);
          data.push(row);
     }

     self.add(tableview);
     tableview.setData(data);
 };
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the example. Anyway, I solved this issue by changing the coding strategy. Output all value from the google distance matrix and google places api, save them all into a database. Call them back with open and select database by joining the tables and put all into tableview. :)